# objective c MPMoviePlayerController wont work on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

Ive got this code from an ebook tutorial on embedding MPMoviePlayerController from a VIEW object but it just dont work at all on iOS 4.3, it just gives me a black screen. I've tried looking at other sources and they have the same source code. Can anyone help me on finding what is the problem in this code.

Thanks

```
    - (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shawarma" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]; 
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [player.view setFrame: movieHolder.bounds]; 
    [movieHolder addSubview: player.view];
    [player play];
}
```

My VIEW object has a dimension of 400 x 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From the MPMoviePlayerController class reference guidelines  Consider
>   a movie player view to be an **opaque** structure.
>
> You can add your own custom subviews to layer content on top of the
>   movie but **you must never modify any of its existing subviews.**
>
> In addition to layering content on top of a movie, you can provide
>   custom background content by adding
>   subviews to the view in the backgroundView

MPMoviePlayerController it self has a property view to present the video

Hope this [LINK](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/play-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-ios-3-0-and-3-24-0) might help you

Comment: um, the code he posted is not modifying and of the players subviews.

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you explain me on layman's term. Im really new on iOS programming. Thanks again..

Comment: What is your movieHolder ? are you sure you **size the frame** correctly ?

Comment: it is a view object. I declared it in my .h view controller and connected it in my xib file.

Comment: What is the frame size of your movieHolder view ?

Comment: How the hell people can vote down of my answer without giving any conclusion ?

Comment: @Praveen-K...found an answer on your given link, i just declared `MPMoviePlayerController *player` in my .h ViewController. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh great, then you accept the answer so it might help for other in future :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with MPMoviePlayer and ios 4.3 i am working on an application that plays movie from a server and this is working fine for me. I request you to check

1. Path of you resource try some hardcode path.
2. Frame of the MoviePlayer.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nishant, i was able to solve the problem by declaring MPMoviePlayerController *player in my .h ViewController. Thanks anyway for your answer.